# Python 3 parse xml file with ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

Help, I have the following XML file that I am trying to read and extract data from, below is an extract from the xml file,

`<Variable name="Inboard_ED_mm" state="Output" type="double[]">17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154<Properties><Property name="index">25</Property><Property name="description"></Property><Property name="upperBound">0</Property><Property name="hasUpperBound">false</Property><Property name="lowerBound">0</Property><Property name="hasLowerBound">false</Property><Property name="units"></Property><Property name="enumeratedValues"></Property><Property name="enumeratedAliases"></Property><Property name="validity">true</Property><Property name="autoSize">true</Property><Property name="userSlices"></Property></Properties></Variable>`

I am trying to extract the following, `17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154`

I have worked through the example here, [xml.etree.ElementTree — The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and I can get the example to work, but when I modify the code for the above xml, the code returns nothing!

Here is my code,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
work_dir = r"C:\Temp\APROCONE\Python"

with open(model.xml, 'rt') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()

for Variable in root.findall('Variable'):
    type = Variable.find('type').text
    name = Variable.get('name')
    print(name, type)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit:
Thanks to everyone who has commented. With with your advice I have had a play and a search and got the following code,

```
with open(os.path.join(work_dir, "output.txt"), "w") as f:
for child1Tag in root.getchildren():
    for child2Tag in child1Tag.getchildren():
        for child3Tag in child2Tag.getchildren():
            for child4Tag in child3Tag.getchildren():
                for child5Tag in child4Tag.getchildren():
                    name = child5Tag.get('name')
                    if name == "Inboard_ED_mm":
                        print(child5Tag.attrib, file=f)
                        print(name, file=f)
                        print(child5Tag.text, file=f)
```

To return the following,

```
{'name': 'Inboard_ED_mm', 'state': 'Output', 'type': 'double[]'}
Inboard_ED_mm
17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154, 17.154
```

I know, not the best code in the world, any ideas on how to streamline the code would very welcome.

Comment: _"below is an extract from the xml file"_ - The problem could be that `Variable` is in a default namespace. Do you have a `xmlns="???"` anywhere in the XML that's not shown?

Comment: @Daniel Haley, thanks for responding, sorry bit no I can not find 'xmlns' in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say the above is an "extract" of the XML file.  The structure of the XML is important.  Does the above just sit inside the root node?

```
for Variable in root.findall('Variable'):
    print(Variable.get('name'), Variable.text)
```

Or does it exist somewhere deeper in the XML tree structure, at a known level?

```
for Variable in root.findall('Path/To/Variable'):
    print(Variable.get('name'), Variable.text)
```

Or does it exist at some unspecified deeper level in the XML tree structure?

```
for Variable in root.findall('.//Variable'):
    print(Variable.get('name'), Variable.text)
```

---

Demonstrating the last two:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> src = """
<root>
 <SubNode>
  <Variable name='x'>17.154, ..., 17.154<Properties>...</Properties></Variable>
  <Variable name='y'>14.174, ..., 15.471<Properties>...</Properties></Variable>
 </SubNode>
</root>"""
>>> root = ET.fromstring(src)
>>> for Variable in root.findall('SubNode/Variable'):
        print(Variable.get('name'), Variable.text)


x 17.154, ..., 17.154
y 14.174, ..., 15.471
>>>
>>> for Variable in root.findall('.//Variable'):
        print(Variable.get('name'), Variable.text)


x 17.154, ..., 17.154
y 14.174, ..., 15.471
```

---

**Update**

Based on your new/clearer/updated question, you are looking for:

```
for child in root.findall("*/*/*/*/Variable[@name='Inboard_ED_mm']"):
    print(child.attrib, file=f)
    print(child.get('name'), file=f)
    print(child.text, file=f)
```

or

```
for child in root.findall(".//Variable[@name='Inboard_ED_mm']"):
    print(child.attrib, file=f)
    print(child.get('name'), file=f)
    print(child.text, file=f)
```

With the exact tagnames of tags 1 through 4 are, we could give you a more exact XPath, instead of relying on `*/*/*/*/`.

Comment: thanks for your response, after a bit of playing and searching it sits deep in the root node! I have added the code in the original question.

Comment: Ah - you are looking for the `Variable` tag with an exact `name` attribute.   There is an XPath for that.  See update.

Answer (score 1):

Your root node is already the `Variable` tag, so you won't find anything with a `Variable` tag with `findall`, which can only search for child nodes. You should simply output the `text` attribute of the root node instead:

```
print(root.text)
```

Comment: thanks for you response, you answer has helped me find a solution.